# How to save selected item in Outlook VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to save the selected item in Outlook. With the below code, I am able to save the item but it saves only the 1st item and not the selected item.

What do I need to change in order to save the selected item?

```
Dim oOlApp As Object, objNmSpc As Object, ofldr As Object
Dim myCopiedItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim myNewFolder  As String

Set oOlApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set oOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
End If
Err.Clear

Set objNmSpc = oOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set ofldr = objNmSpc.PickFolder
If Not ofldr Is Nothing Then MsgBox ofldr

Dim oItem As Object
For Each oItem In ofldr.Items
    If oOlApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1) = True Then
        oItem.SaveAs Sheet1.Range("V5").Value & oItem.Subject & ".msg", olMSG
        match.Offset(, 7).Value = oItem.SenderName & "-" & oItem.Subject & "-" & oItem.ReceivedTime
        match.Offset(, 8).Value = VBA.Environ("Username") & "- " & VBA.Now
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next oItem
```

Answer (score 0):

The following line would not run without an error

```
If oOlApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1) = True Then
```

Plus you are calling `Exit sub`, which means only one item can ever get processed.

There is absolutely no reason to loop through all items in a folder. Change the loop to the following

```
For Each oItem In oOlApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        oItem.SaveAs Sheet1.Range("V5").Value & oItem.Subject & ".msg", olMSG
        match.Offset(, 7).Value = oItem.SenderName & "-" & oItem.Subject & "-" & oItem.ReceivedTime
        match.Offset(, 8).Value = VBA.Environ("Username") & "- " & VBA.Now
Next oItem
```